# Microsoft Graph Toolkit: get logged in user

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using the Login component `<Login />` of the Microsoft Graph Toolkit (React flavor). How can I retrieve the display name and User Principal Name of the logged in user?

I see that the component has a `loginCompleted` prop, but the user is not passed as argument.

Comment: Can you get the `userDetails` object from the login component? 
in js, something like:

let person = document.querySelector('mgt-login')
console.log(person.userDetails) 

This object should contain both the upn and the displayName properties.

Comment: That's the kind of info I am looking for. Obviously I don't want a DOM method such as querySelector and I am looking for a built-in method. There must be one as other components such as Person or Avatar can get the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting advice from Microsoft, and reviewing [a sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/meeting-moderator-sample/), here is the code I came up with:

```
    <Login
      loginCompleted={(e) => {
        Providers.globalProvider.graph.client.api('me').get()
          .then(gotMe => DoStuff(gotMe));
      }}
      logoutCompleted={(e) => { }}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

So it's definitely possible to do this, but be aware that it's not 100% safe (what I mean is, don't rely on this to send to a backend API as a way to *authenticate* or *identify* the user). However, for display on the page you can use something like:

```
import { Providers } from '@microsoft/mgt';
...
let provider = Providers.globalProvider;
let account = provider._userAgentApplication.account;

// now you have access to: account.accountIdentifier, account.name, account.userName, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I need is a way to identify the logged in user, that's why I am trying to use the Login feature and move away from a global provider.

Comment: You mean like identify for use when calling an API?

Comment: Yes, I am calling APIs such as me/events or the SharePoint API, and I want to capture the name of the logged in user. The Login component looks safer to me than a provider.

Comment: The Login component is using this same provider under the covers.

Comment: I understand, but because it does the actual login step I would expect this to be safer than taking the provider value directly. If for some reason the login fails, the user info won't be provided.

Comment: So your best bet in that case is to use MSAL 2.0 directly, I'd think